# Mesh Noise in Three.js Compared to Blender

Tags: three.js, webgl, blender

- I have a mesh that's a photogrammetry scan, so it's a bit dirty.
- I've set it up in Blender and Three.js the same way, flatShading, no lights, just pure diffuse/texture shading.
- In Blender, it renders perfectly, displaying the texture as-is. But in Three.js (and pure webgl) it renders very noisy.
- I've tried flatShading, smoothShading, merging vertices in Three.js; still have the noise/artifacts.
- See the comparison image below (zoomed in to the problem area). Blender on the left, Three.js on the right.
  [image]

Does anyone know what's causing this? It is a dirty mesh, but Blender is handling it really well, just curious why I cannot reproduce in Three.js.

Comment: What image are you using for your texture? Can we see it? It could be a mip-mapping issue.

Comment: @Marquizzo i cannot share the image, sorry, but it's a head scan, so it's a typical head skin texture map. I'll look into mip-mapping, forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting a few things:

```
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio * 1.5); // looked a bit better than * 1 for whatever reason

texture.minFilter   = THREE.NearestFilter;
texture.magFilter   = THREE.NearestFilter;
```

Now my model looks exactly like Blender.

Comment: I wouldn't set pixel ratio to 1.5 on a whim. This more than doubles the number of pixels you need to render, which could have big performance costs. For example a display with 1920x1080=2.1M pixels. Increasing this to 1.5 means you're rendering 2880x1620=4.6M pixels.

Comment: @Marquizzo - it's not for real time, just generating some data. I've added a downsampler to deal with that.